# Failed to resolve: com.firebase:fire-client-android:2.4.2

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm working with firebase.
This is the error on app/build.gradle:

```
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.firebase:fire-client-android:2.4.0

Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.3.1
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Here is my module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.prueba.android.connect4"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/connect4Lib.jar')
    compile 'com.firebase:fire-client-android:2.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.3.1'
}
```

And top-level gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {

    jcenter() {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter(){
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the 2.4.0 version of Firebase, the dependency is `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0`. You're missing the **base** part

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to move to google firebase as older firebase APIs have been deprecated and will be removed in future.
Change your gradle to include

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.1' //For realtime database
```

Checkout [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for more information.

Comment: Currently Firebase is recommending Android users to keep using the Legacy Version if they use authentication since there are issues with The Authentication as displayed in this issues:  https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/16001

Comment: But from the question it seems @Pablo is starting afresh. So he should not use old APIs. The issue will get resolved sooner or later.

Comment: Just helping him get all the information so he can make an informed decision...not assuming anything, but you are right  if someone is starting  just for educational purposes he/she would be in a better  position using the new firebase

Comment: AFAIK the issue is related to authentication with other providers and not with Email/password authentication. I have an app working perfectly with google auth and Email/password auth.

Comment: Sorry, but this job was done by someone else. I can't change that, I don't know how. There is no solution using this code?

Comment: Try compile `'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'` and  compile `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'`